# how to pass variables and add condition to exexute task only when the condition is met

Tags: yaml

there are 10 such task , and i'm trying to pass the solution names from paramters / variables so that only
those solutions which are present in paramters / variables will execute .

task: microsoft.PowerPlatformExportSolution@0
Name: Unmanaged Solution
inputs:
authenticationType:SPN
SolutionName: Account

task: microsoft-PowerPlatformExportSolution@0
displayName: Unmanaged Solution
inputs:
authenticationType: SPN
SolutionName: contact

variables:

- name: SolutionNames
  value: 'account,contact,lead'
  but it is taking all of them in place of solutionnames